# ButterKnife IllegalStateException when using ViewStubs in layout

Tags: android, butterknife, viewstub

Using `ViewStubs` makes a layout more lightweight and improves performance. I have a few layouts that are to be inflated in `ViewStubs`. The respective layouts' individual components are defined in my activity and bound using `ButterKnife`.

However, during runtime, `ButterKnife` throws an exception that none of the components defined can be found.

I understand that a layout is only inflated into the `ViewStub` after calling `.inflate()` method, but is there a way it can work with `ButterKnife`?

Answer (score 0):

You try `ButterKnife.bind` method after `ViewStub.inflate()`.